# Unicode input with plain LuaTeX

Tags: luatex, unicode, plain-tex

```
grün
gr\"un
\bye
```

yields

```
grn
grün
```

Is it possible to have the Unicode ü correctly rendered with
plain LuaTeX?

---

Would it also be possible with plain TeX and a METAFONT font?
Or would a METAFONT font *have to* be converted into something
else if one wanted to use it with Unicode input?

Comment: Try `\input luaotfload.sty
\font\lmr = name:"lmroman10-regular"
gr\"un
\lmr
grün
\bye`

Comment: METAFONT fonts have 256 slots. Actually it is theoretically possible to have more “planes”, but with severe limitations on the font metrics: two characters in corresponding slots in two different planes must have the same metrics. You *can* draw characters with MF, then convert them to build an OpenType font with some tracing program (which is what has basically been done to produce the CM Unicode fonts, for instance).

Comment: @egreg, so, with an appropriately limited font, Unicode input can be mapped to the appropriate glyphs, even with plain TeX (not necessarily LuaTeX)?

Comment: @Toothrot I'm not sure I understand.

Comment: @egreg, let's say I have a small METAFONT font with polytonic Greek,
but I want to be able to type alpha using the Unicode alpha
rather than a Latin "a".  Would there be any obstacle to that (in plain TeX, not LuaTeX)?

Comment: @Toothrot The standard LaTeX fonts for Greek have an alpha in the slot for a. :-) But you'd have to teach plain TeX to transform UTF-8 into a proper slot number.

Comment: I’m trying to do something similar with mathematical symbols in text mode (e.g. ∀z∈x z∉z), and the following works for me:
    　　　　　
\usepackage{fontspec}
    　　　　
\setmainfont{Latin Modern Math}[Mapping=tex-text, ItalicFont={CMU Serif Italic}, BoldFont={CMU Serif Bold}, BoldItalicFont={CMU Serif BoldItalic}]

Answer (score 1):

You *might* use METAFONT fonts:

```
\catcode`ü=\active
\protected\def ü{\"u}

grün
gr\"un
\fontname\font
\bye
```

[image]

You might study sections from 6.3 to 6.5 of the LuaTeX manual to see whether an approach with virtual fonts is feasible. However, this would require extensive work for defining virtual fonts from existing ones. Using European Modern fonts (that are T1 encoded, using LaTeX lingo) might be easier.

On the other hand, you can easily inject a font loader in LuaTeX and use OpenType fonts. For instance

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\font\tenrm="Latin Modern Roman"
\tenrm

grün
gr\"un
\fontname\font

\bye
```

[image]

Note that the second “grün” prints wrongly, because accents are not in the slots used by plain TeX and one needs to redefine the accent commands, for instance

```
\input luaotfload.sty

\def\"#1{#1^^^^0308}

\font\tenrm="Latin Modern Roman"
\tenrm

grün
gr\"un
\fontname\font

\bye
```

[image]

Redefining a few accents is obviously easier than *many* active characters.

Comment: Compare the 2 words "grün". The position of the dots is different. The second "grün" looks wrong. Is there a way to fix this? Can they be made equal?

Comment: OK, for MinionPro, they look equal, but when I copy and paste them, only the first "ü" appears correctly, the second one loses its dots (result: "u"). What is happening here?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not an expert on this, so I cannot exactly explain how it works and why it works and stuff. But since nobody gave you satisfying answer on your second question sofar, I try to contribute myself. So, I guess I have a solution if your concern is using German. If you also want to use the Greek alphabet or math symbols and stuff, then I am afraid, this cannot work without LuaTeX or something similar that supports Unicode.

This problem is solved in the Czech-Slovak distribution of TeX, which, if I understand it corretly, has its own slightly modified fonts and internally it transforms the utf8 input into iso8859-2 coding, where all the Czech, as well as German, characters appear. See https://www.ctan.org/pkg/csplain

You can write, for example

```
Příliš žluťoučký kůň úpěl ďábelské ódy.

„Fix, Schwyz!“, quäkt Jürgen blöd vom Paß.

\bye
```

And after compiling using `pdfcsplain` instead of `pdftex`, you get the right result.