# Why à becomes ŕ in luatex with latin modern?

Tags: luatex, latin-modern

Running luatex (not lualatex) on a file with the following content:

```
\font\lmrten=cs-lmr10
\lmrten
à

\bye
```

outputs a PDF file containing a 'ŕ', not a 'à'.

Why?
And hox to fix it?

Comment: The fonts starting with `cs-` are IL2 encoded and IL2 has the `ŕ` a the position where Unicode has `à`. In LuaTeX you would normally use Unicode encoded OpenType fonts instead. Is there a reason why you selected `cs-lmr10`?

Comment: You have posted here in UTF-8,  the cs-fonts are roughly latin-2  which does not have à

Comment: As an alternative `\input lmfonts à\bye` works, not sure if that is what you are looking for.

Comment: There's also [Unicode input with plain LuaTeX - TeX - LaTeX Stack Exchange](https://tex.stackexchange.com/questions/552065/unicode-input-with-plain-luatex) which appears to demonstrate an approach that *works*. Not sure what Luaotfload is though.

Comment: @user202729 Luaotfload is a module to load system fonts in OTF (OpenType) format for use by Lua(La)TeX. My comment above basically follows the approach of your linked question as also suggested by Marcel Krüger in his comment here. `\input lmfonts` loads `lmfonts.tex` (from csplain) that uses luaotfload to load `lmroman10-regular.otf` that can handle Unicode characters like à in the source code.